# Connect to Flask websocket from python code

Tags: python, flask, websocket

I'm interested in creating bidirectional exchange between Flask server and client. Seems that websockets are very convinient for achieving my goal. But i stucked on implementation. I've created simple Flask app with Flask-SocketIO like described in docs:

```
from flask_socketio import SocketIO
from flask import Flask

app = Flask(__name__)
app.config['SECRET_KEY'] = 'secret!'
socketio = SocketIO(app)

@socketio.on('message')
def handle_message(message):
    print('received message: ' + message)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    socketio.run(app)
```

Client uses websocket-client package and looks as follows:

```
from websocket import create_connection

ws = create_connection("ws://localhost:5000")
ws.send("hello world")
```

In this configuration it doesn't work.

Also i tried to use Flask-Sockets on the server side:

```
from flask import Flask
from flask_sockets import Sockets    

app = Flask(__name__)
sockets = Sockets(app)


@sockets.route('/')
def echo_socket(ws):
    while not ws.closed:
        message = ws.receive()
        print(message)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run()
```

It also doesn't work. I found several posts in some places (for example [there](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44706033/connecting-to-a-flask-websocket-using-python) and [there](https://gist.github.com/punchagan/53600958c1799c2dcf26)) with "working" examples but actually they all don't work.

So is it possible to do what i need? If yes, how to do that? If no, what is alternatives?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

flask sokets.io actually are not a websockets, they are SocketsIO. If one wants to integrate real WebSocket in his flask application he could use [this](https://github.com/heroku-python/flask-sockets) project.